# iPhone SDK - Big UITableViewCell

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit, uitableview

I just wanted to know what kind of UITableViewCell are on applications such as "Mail", and how to set one up. They seem to have much more length for extra text and other objects. A good sample project or some code/reference link would get me started.

Thanks,

Kevin

Comment: vodkhang: Only if more than half of his questions have answers that deserve his acceptance. The bigger problem is that Kevin mistagged this question and at least one other as [cocoa] [xcode] when both this question and that one have nothing to do with either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This [custom UITableViewCell tutorial](http://adeem.me/blog/2009/05/30/iphone-sdk-tutorial-part-6-creating-custom-uitableviewcell-using-interface-builder-uitableview/) is good for starting. This is [another, similar one](http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder)